# Difficulty finding out how dynamic ajax content is loaded

Tags: ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

So I want to crawl information about the following 2 products:
1. http://www.dollargeneral.com/product/index.jsp?productId=86154836
2. http://www.dollargeneral.com/product/index.jsp?productId=58607576

Product No.2 offers "save 5% on all order with Auto delivery"

Product No.1 doesn't

When I crawl this page, the "div" about the offer part doesn't show up, so I think this information is loaded by ajax.

Now my questions is: after using chrome dev tool to check the "Network" using XHR filter, both URLs only send 1 request that contains seemingly useless information.

So where is the offer information coming from? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

These are two different products. One simply has the offer attached to it while the other does not. Some products include the offer and others don't.

Comment: yeah, I just want to know "how" the offer is being attached. Clearly, it is not statically typed, but loaded in a dynamic way, i want to know how that dynamic process works.